# Error 1316. The specified account already exists. Visual Studio 2017: Failed to install package. Return Code 1603

Tags: visual-studio, error-handling, visual-studio-2017, return-code

Need to install Visual Studio for school, but run into this and one other error.

```
Visual Studio fails to install "Microsoft.Net.CoreUWP,version=1.1.32" and "Win10SDK_10.0.16299,version=10.0.16299.0".

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Log for "Microsoft.Net.CoreUWP,version=1.1.32" :
Package 'Microsoft.Net.CoreUWP,version=1.1.32' failed to install.
    Search URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.Net.CoreUWP;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1316
    Details
        MSI: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.CoreUWP,version=1.1.32\netfx_NETCoreUWP.msi, Properties:  REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1  MSIFASTINSTALL="7" 
        Return code: 1603
        Return code details: Fatal error during installation.
        Message Id: 1316
        Message Details: The specified account already exists.

   Log
        C:\Users\Kaleb\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20180123192925_162_Microsoft.Net.CoreUWP.log
    Impacted workloads
        Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.27128.1)
    Impacted components
        Universal Windows Platform tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26906.1)
        Universal Windows Platform tools for Cordova (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Cordova,version=15.0.27005.2)
        Universal Windows Platform tools for Xamarin (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin,version=15.0.27005.2)


+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


Log for "Win10SDK_10.0.16299,version=10.0.16299.0" :
Package 'Win10SDK_10.0.16299,version=10.0.16299.0' failed to install.
    Search URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Win10SDK_10.0.16299;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1316
    Details
        Command executed: "c:\windows\syswow64\\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -InputFormat None "$ErrorActionPreference="""Stop"""; $VerbosePreference="""Continue"""; $CeipSetting="""on"""; $ScriptPath="""C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Win10SDK_10.0.16299,version=10.0.16299.0\WinSdkInstall.ps1"""; $SetupExe="""winsdksetup.exe"""; $SetupLogFolder="""windowssdk"""; $PackageId="""Win10SDK_10.0.16299"""; $LogFile="""C:\Users\Kaleb\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20180123192925_181_Win10SDK_10.0.16299.log"""; $SetupParameters="""/features OptionId.AvrfExternal OptionId.UWPManaged OptionId.WindowsSoftwareLogoToolkit OptionId.SigningTools OptionId.UWPLocalized OptionId.UWPCPP OptionId.DesktopCPPx64 OptionId.DesktopCPPx86 OptionID.DesktopCPPARM OptionID.DesktopCPPARM64 OptionId.MSIInstallTools /quiet /norestart"""; (gc $ScriptPath | out-string) | Invoke-Expression; if (!$?) { exit 1603 } elseif ($LastExitCode) { exit $LastExitCode }"
        Return code: 1316
        Return code details: The specified account already exists.
    Log
        C:\Users\Kaleb\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20180123192925_181_Win10SDK_10.0.16299.log
    Impacted workloads
        Desktop development with C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop,version=15.0.27102.0)
        Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.27128.1)
    Impacted components
        Universal Windows Platform tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26906.1)
        Universal Windows Platform tools for Cordova (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Cordova,version=15.0.27005.2)
        Universal Windows Platform tools for Xamarin (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin,version=15.0.27005.2)
        Visual C++ tools for CMake (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project,version=15.0.27019.1)
        Windows 10 SDK (10.0.16299.0) for Desktop C++ [x86 and x64] (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.16299.Desktop,version=15.0.27128.1)
        Windows 10 SDK (10.0.16299.0) for UWP: C#, VB, JS (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.16299.UWP,version=15.0.27128.1)
        Windows 10 SDK (10.0.16299.0) for UWP: C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.16299.UWP.Native,version=15.0.27128.1)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

In [this page](http://kb.palisade.com/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=1495) there is some info about `Error 1316. the specified account already exists`:

> Are you installing with full administrative rights? To make certain
>   that you are, **right-click the installer and select Run as
>   administrator**.
>
> ---
>
> **The next most likely explanation is some bad registry entries:**
>
> Microsoft offers a tool to solve these sorts of install and uninstall
>   problems; please see **[Fix problems that block programs from being
>   installed or removed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed)**.
>
> When the **fix-it** tool asks what you're trying to
>   install, select **"not listed"** unless you're installing the exact same
>   version that was previously installed. For example, both 7.5.0 and
>   7.5.1 would show up as 7.5 in the list in the fix-it tool, but they are different installers so you would select "not listed" if you're
>   installing 7.5.1 over 7.5.0.

---

**Older Section:**

If above solution dose not work for you, read this part:

**Based on your provided log, It seems in this case »** the *Visual Studio Setup* program need to uninstall `netfx_NETCoreUWP.msi` and `Win10SDK` from your computer but it can not do it, so you can help it with uninstalling them manually *(with your risk)*:

1. Close *Visual Studio Setup* program
2. Go to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.CoreUWP,version=1.1.32`
3. Right click on `netfx_NETCoreUWP.msi` and select *Uninstall*.

---

4. For the second error I think you should open `Programs and Features` from `Control Panel` and uninstall `Microsoft Software Development Kit - Windows 10.0.16299` from there.
5. Run *Visual Studio Setup* program again and go ahead..

Comment: It's not letting me uninstall netfx_NETCoreUWP.msi because it says that it isn't installed. Just to test it, I clicked install netfx_NETCoreUWP.msi, and it said an account already exists

Comment: @K.J.Shamberger, I updated my answer with 2 way to test an solve the problem. Please test them too.

Comment: thanks for the help, everything is up and running fine now!

Comment: @K.J.Shamberger , I'm happy... If My answer helped you. You can marked it as accepted answer.

Comment: I did, but I haven't been on the site long enough, so they don't really let me vote yet...

Comment: The MS tool allowed me to uninstall an ancient photo editing app that gave the above error. THANK YOU! The tool ran for like 15 minutes beating the devil out of the disk.